# Copying files with specific name to a specific folder using python

Tags: python, file, rename

I have a following problem (I am on macOS):
12 usb flash drives are mounted in /Volumes and they have names from cam0 to cam11. Each of the drives have a following structure cam0/DCIM/100HDDVR/C00_0001.mp4, cam1/DCIM/100HDDVR/C01_0001.mp4, etc. In each 100HDDVR folder there will be multiple files so for cam0 for example it will be: C00_0001.mp4, C00_0002.mp4, C00_0003.mp4, etc.
Now I would like to copy it to the desktop, lets say, where a new folder will be created called: recording[adds today date] then create a subfolder shoot1 which will be containing files C00_0001.mp4 through C11_0001.mp4 and create subfolder shoot2 that will be containing C00_0002.mp4 through C11_0002.mp4 and so on until all the files from the flash drives are copied.

So far I managed to copy all files from cam0/DCIM/100HDDVR to a new folder recordings/cam0 but it is not automated enough and I am struggling to update it.

```
def copyy(self):
        root.update_idletasks()
        self.status['text'] = "Files are being copyied, have patience ;)".format(self.status)


        self.source_direcotry0= '/Volumes/CAM0/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry1= '/Volumes/CAM1/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry2= '/Volumes/CAM2/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry3= '/Volumes/CAM3/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry4= '/Volumes/CAM4/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry5= '/Volumes/CAM5/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry6= '/Volumes/CAM6/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry7= '/Volumes/CAM7/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry8= '/Volumes/CAM8/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry9= '/Volumes/CAM9/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry10= '/Volumes/CAM10/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry11= '/Volumes/CAM11/DCIM/100HDDVR'

        self.path0="recording/CAM0"
        self.path1="recording/CAM1"
        self.path2="recording/CAM2"
        self.path3="recording/CAM3"
        self.path4="recording/CAM4"
        self.path5="recording/CAM5"
        self.path6="recording/CAM6"
        self.path7="recording/CAM7"
        self.path8="recording/CAM8"
        self.path9="recording/CAM9"
        self.path10="recording/CAM10"
        self.path11="recording/CAM11"


        self.cam0=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path0)
        self.cam1=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path1)
        self.cam2=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path2)
        self.cam3=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path3)
        self.cam4=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path4)
        self.cam5=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path5)
        self.cam6=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path6)
        self.cam7=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path7)
        self.cam8=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path8)
        self.cam9=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path9)
        self.cam10=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path10)
        self.cam11=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path11)

        self.p.start(1)


        self.work_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.copyy2, args=())
        self.work_thread.start()
        self.work_thread.join()


        self.p.stop()

        self.status['text'] = "Files have been copyied".format(self.status)

    def copyy2(self):

        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry0, self.cam0)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry1, self.cam1)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry2, self.cam2)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry3, self.cam3)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry4, self.cam4)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry5, self.cam5)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry6, self.cam6)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry7, self.cam7)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry8, self.cam8)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry9, self.cam9)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry10, self.cam10)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry11, self.cam11)
```

On top of that how would you tackle this problem so it works on Windows too were when flash drives are mounted you can't see their name and disk letters are always different. Is that even possible?

I hope that I managed to describe it clear enough and thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: consider using python's os.walk()

Answer (score 0):

I would do it another way around :

1. get all files path under /Volume
2. search all files finishing by the extension you Want : [0001.mp4, 0002.mp4, etc..]
3. copy these files to a subdirectory on your desktop.

For (1) you can use :

```
def get_filepaths(directory, extension=None):
    """
    Generate the file names in a directory
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself),
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """
    import os, ntpath
    assert(os.path.isdir(directory)), "The 'directory' parameter is not a directory (%s)"%(directory)

    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.
    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)

            if not ntpath.basename(filepath).startswith("."):
                file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.

    if extension:return [x for  x in file_paths if x.endswith(extension) ]

    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory
```

For (2) and (3) you can use the same fonction in a loop :

```
# this is a pseudo code - no tested and has to be customized 
nb_shoot = n
for shoot_n in range(nb_shoot):
    # 1) looking for files to copy
    nb_zeros  = 3 - len(str(shoot_n)) # calculating the number of 0 to put in front of the filename
    zeros     = "0"*nb_zeros
    extension = "%s%shoot_n.mp4"%(zeros, shoot_n)
    paths_for_the_shoot = get_filepaths("/Volumes/", extension)
    #2) creating a new dir
    current_date = time.time()
    new_dir_name = "recording_%s/shoot_%s"%(current_date , shoot_n )
    os.mkdir(new_dir_name)
    for path in paths_for_the_shoot:
        #copy file
        os.copy(path, new_dir_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help, I have to now wrap my head around it, understand it and try to implement. If I run into some more problems I will get back to you.